# TORQUE Resource Manager does not queue jobs in a normal order

Tags: queue, torque

I have strange behavior with torque. I set a unique queue to torque every jobs runs should have the same priority but when I submit some of them, they seems to run randomly.
To submit them, I use this command `qsub -q prod script.sh`

For example, with qstat command I have this.

```
4566.localhost             ..._1.PBS_1_2.sh thomas.pedot           0 Q prod
4567.localhost             ..._1.PBS_1_3.sh thomas.pedot           0 Q prod
4568.localhost             ..._1.PBS_1_4.sh thomas.pedot    20:16:34 C prod
4569.localhost             ..._1.PBS_1_5.sh thomas.pedot    17:55:30 R prod
4570.localhost             ..._1.PBS_1_6.sh thomas.pedot           0 Q prod
```

Why jobs number 4568 and 4569 ran before 4566 4567, etc ?

What do I miss ?

Update:
the result of qstat -f on previous jobs :

```
Job_Name = SCRIPT.sh
Job_Owner = thomas.pedot@localhost
job_state = Q
queue = prod
server = localhost
Checkpoint = u
ctime = Wed Aug  9 11:09:40 2017
Error_Path = xxxx:/dev/null
Hold_Types = n
Join_Path = n
Keep_Files = n
Mail_Points = a
mtime = Wed Aug  9 11:09:40 2017
Output_Path = xxxx:/dev/null
Priority = 0
qtime = Wed Aug  9 11:09:40 2017
Rerunable = True
Resource_List.neednodes = 1
Resource_List.nodect = 1
Resource_List.nodes = 1
Resource_List.walltime = 168:00:00
substate = 10
Variable_List = xxxx
euser = thomas.pedot
egroup = users
queue_rank = 606
queue_type = E
comment = Not Running: Queue job limit has been reached.
etime = Wed Aug  9 11:09:40 2017
submit_args = -q prod -e /dev/null -o /dev/null SCRIPT.sh
fault_tolerant = False
job_radix = 0
submit_host = localhost
```

I don't see anything different with later jobs.

Thanks a lot,
Thomas

Comment: Check the reason for not running jobs 4566 and 4567 in the output of `qstat -f 4566 4567`.

Comment: What scheduler do you run? The server log should say something about that (`Job Run at request of...`).

Comment: I am using torque scheduler. If it can be useful, here you can find the server log : [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/cKQxX9Jq) 

I wonder if it would be better to install maui.

Comment: I presume by "torque scheduler" you mean `pbs_sched`, which simply runs jobs in FIFO order (i.e., submission order). You should do as Dmitri suggested and check the `qstat -f` output of 4566 and 4567. If that doesn't help, check the logs. The ones you uploaded don't give enough information. Try increasing `log_level` in `qmgr` (set it to 7), then wait for it to show up again. It should indicate a node where the job will try to run. Then check the `pbs_mom` log and `/var/log/messages` for details. You may also need to increase the `pbs_mom` logging depth.